# Indicating to main thread that Async call for calendar access has been completed

Tags: ios, objective-c, multithreading, asynchronous, grand-central-dispatch

I want calendar access to the user's iphone for that i am using the async call

```
__block NSMutableArray* someData;
[eventStore requestAccessToEntityType:EKEntityTypeEvent completion:^(BOOL granted, NSError *error) {
    //We are going to fetch events from today to the next 1 year
    if (granted) {
        //Processing
        [someData addObject:@"Something Added"]
    }

}];
```

I basically want to do some processing and then signal the main thread which is executing in another object that the processing has been done on `someData` and that it should now access it.

I have attempted wrapping this in a dispatch group like this

```
dispatch_group_t group = dispatch_group_create();

dispatch_group_async(group,dispatch_get_global_queue(DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_HIGH, 0), ^ {
    calendarData = [calender returnCalenderEvents];
});

dispatch_group_notify(group,dispatch_get_global_queue(DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_HIGH, 0), ^ {
    NSLog(@"%@",calendarData);
});
```

however since the call is async it still notifies the group of completion before any actual completion has beeen done.

Basically how can i just signal the main thread that processing has been done on the async call, get the results and start doing your own processing

Comment: Why not you are accessing the main thread inside the secondary one. And then notify from here only.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add a notification on viewDidLoad
 `[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self selector:@selector(calendarPermissionGranted:) name:@"calendarProcessingCompleted" object:nil];`

once the calendar permission granted it will post the notification from here.

```
 __block NSMutableArray* someData;
    [eventStore requestAccessToEntityType:EKEntityTypeEvent completion:^(BOOL granted, NSError *error) {
        //We are going to fetch events from today to the next 1 year
        if (granted) {
            //Processing
            [someData addObject:@"Something Added"]

             dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
                    //notify your class that processing has been done.
                  [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter]   postNotificationName:@"calendarProcessingCompleted" object:nil userInfo:nil];
              });
        }
}];
```

Capture it in method

```
-(void)calendarPermissionGranted:(NSNotification *)noti{

}
```

May be this what you are looking for.

Comment: I a not doing any UI related so i don't need access to the main thread. I just need a way for the view controller to get notified that the calendar object has done processing and now you can do your own processing.

Comment: @WinCoder I have updated my answer may be this will help you else I don't understand what you wanted to do.

Comment: ahhh yes i was looking exactly for this sort of thing, where one object can notify another object without having any sort of reference to each other.